# jQuery Strange behavior using .html() and .empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some weird behavior from my jQuery. I am running `jQuery 1.10.2` from google's ajax api.

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) the `.html()` function is supposed to call the function `.empty()` before inserting the text. My problem is that I have a div container with a unique id and when I insert text using the `.html()` function the default text is cleared and my desired text is inserted, which is supposed to happen.

```
<div id="xmlContent">
    this is a test <!-- Default Text -->
</div>
```

*But* if I click my "add text button" again the new text is just appended to the previously generated content instead of replacing it. Further still if I keep clicking on the button the new content nests within the first child element.

```
<div id="xmlContent">
    <code>
        &lt;code&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;fred<br>
        <address></address><br>
        <issitelocation></issitelocation><br>
    </code>
    <name>fred</name><br>
    <address>addres</address><br>
    <issitelocation></issitelocation><br>
</div>
```

On a related topic, `.empty()` clears the default text, but refuses to clear any generated content.

I have the code in a jsfiddle right here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jarquafelmu/jEycH/).

Also the code is here

```
function generateXML() {
    xmlHTML += '<name>' + $('#locationName').val() + '</name><br />';
    xmlHTML += '<address>' + $('#address').val() + '</address><br />';
    xmlHTML += '<isSiteLocation>' + $('#isPathwaySite').val() + '</isSiteLocation><br />';
    xmlHTML = xmlHTML.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');
    xmlHTML = '<code>'+xmlHTML+'</code>';
}


function populateXMLContainer() {
    $('#xmlContent').html(xmlHTML);
}

$(function() {
    $('#generateXML').click(function() {
        generateXML();
        populateXMLContainer();
    });
});
```

Please help, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**Clarifying Note**
The reason for the `&lt;` and the `&gt;` is because I'm trying to create an xml generator for myself.

Comment: Just set `xmlHTML = ''` in the first line of `generateXML` method.. Since `var xmlHTML` is being shared , it holds the previous values that is being appended in the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first line of the function generateXML is doing a concatenation of what it was the first time.  On the first pass through xmlHTML is an empty string and every pass after that it's just increasing by what it was the previous time.

Change:

```
xmlHTML += '<name>' + $('#locationName').val() + '</name><br />';
```

To Be:

```
xmlHTML = '<name>' + $('#locationName').val() + '</name><br />';
```

Comment: Oh wow... I've been having trouble with other jQuery code so I didn't even see how simple this problem really was. Haha, blinded by the simplicity. Thank you.